# I have docker installed - how to edit iptables of machine?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, docker

On a machine that has docker installed, I am doing a `sudo iptables -L`, 
and get:

```
root@dockertest:~# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 8364 packets, 729K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination   

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7868 packets, 515K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Am I seeing the correct ipTables of my machine here? Or how to edit the physical machine iptables?

I want to let 22000 through from the outside, curently it seems to be closed:

```
nmap -sV -p 22000 1.2.3.4 
Host is up (0.038s latency).
PORT      STATE  SERVICE VERSION
22000/tcp closed unknown

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.73 seconds
```

Isn't above in contradiction with the iptable?

**tl;dr** I need to forward 22000 to the Docker Container. In essence a client from the outside world must get though the iptables of the physical machine and then get through the whatever firewall the docker has running

Comment: First, post `iptables -nvL` to show in and out interfaces and do this for filter and nat tables (`-t filter` and `-t nat`). Then post your nmap command line, this doesn't make sense to post a result without the test content. And, the most important thing : **explain what you want to do precisely**. If you want to forward a port to a container, you don't need to edit iptables at all, `docker run` has `-p <port_host>:<port_container>` option.

Comment: Updated my question. I need to forward 22000 to the Docker Container. In essence a client from the outside world must get though the iptables of the physical machine and then get through the whatever firewall the docker has running.

Answer (score 3):

Docker is not *"running a firewall"* itself, it uses host iptables and its rules are bound to the docker bridge interface (`docker0` by default).

As you want to forward a host's port to a docker container, you don't need to edit iptables rules, `docker run` [provides option](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) `-p hostPort:containerPort` to do this and will handle all iptables rules itself.

The container port must be [exposed to the docker bridge in your Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose).

For instance, let's say you want to run a nginx container and expose its port 80 to host's port 20000, then you would run :

```
docker run -d -p 20000:80 nginx:latest
```